# How to handle duplicate key in query parameters in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am creating an endpoint where I can get All the projects available in my database.
I have added pagination capability as well. Everything is working as expected.

I can send the request like below

```
http://localhost:8081/api/projects?page=5
```

But if I send a link like below

```
http://localhost:8081/api/projects?page=5&page=6
```

I need to figure out how I can validate this may be I can use only the last value (6) or error out

I am new to Springboot and have tried the solutions mentioned in Stackoverflow without luck.

Any thoughts on this?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Mapping a Multi-Value Parameter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param#mapping-a-multi-value-parameter)

A single @RequestParam can have multiple values:

```java
@GetMapping("/api/foos")
@ResponseBody
public String getFoos(@RequestParam List<String> id) {
    return "IDs are " + id;
}
```

And Spring MVC will map a comma-delimited id parameter:

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-basics/api/foos?id=1,2,3
----
IDs are [1,2,3]
```

or a list of separate id parameters:

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-basics/api/foos?id=1&id=2
----
IDs are [1,2]
```

Comment: I used this method and got the first id value for pagination.